# How to hide tabbar in Android with Titanium SDK 3.x?

Tags: android, android-layout, titanium, titanium-mobile

I want to **hide or visible false** my Tabbar in my Application for Android. I am using Titanium SDK 3.x. Any suggestion or help is appreciated.

May be possible with .XML file like **"tab Style or Theme"**

Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

```
var tabGroup = Titanium.UI.createTabGroup({
    backgroundImage: 'NewTabBackground.png',
    navBarHidden: true

});

Ti.App.customTabGroupDashBoard = tabGroup;


var tab1 = Titanium.UI.createTab({    
    title: 'Title One',
    window: win1
});

var tab2 = Titanium.UI.createTab({    
    title: 'Title Two',
    window: win2
});


tabGroup.addTab(tab1);
tabGroup.addTab(tab2);

// open tab group
return tabGroup;
```

use this `Ti.App.customTabGroupDashBoard` to access your tabGroup globally anywhere.

Comment: thanks for your nice help..

But, this is not useful for me... I want to hide tabbar in First window or show tabbar in Bottom side in Android Device.. with Titanium 3.x SDK

Comment: I am not getting this hiding the tabGroup on first window, can you show me ur tabGroup code and window code....

Comment: sorry for that, I have not problem for sending my code. But you can try your default demo code which is provided by Titanium Default App. In that I want to set my custom Tabbar for this I want to hide default  tabbar in Android.

In iOS we have add any view in Tabbar but in Android have not possible... 
If you have any other solution then plz help me...
any suggestion is very appreciated.

Answer (score -3):

This is a property on the window you are using to show the tabbar.  There is a property on Titanium.UI.Window called tabBarHidden that you can set to true.  See:
http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Window

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your early revert.
But, this is only for iOS. I include my Question. 
I Have need for Android...